# Add both a vertical side caption and a normal caption to a picture

Tags: floats, captions

Is it possible to add a caption to the side of the picture, written vertically in small size (for the credits), while below the picture is the normal caption?

[image]

---

[EDIT]
Minor issue: why is it that if I write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \copyrightbox
        {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic}}
        {(c) Someone}
    \caption{Blah}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

the caption goes further away from the picture, while if I just replace `[width=\textwidth]{pic}` with `[width=.9\textwidth]{pic}` it comes out at the usual distance?

Comment: Is the "side caption" actually note with information of image source? And caption is not numbered?

Comment: Nope, it's not numbered. I made the picture above with Pinta but in the actual document I use the package `caption` and the command `\caption*{}`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The  `copyrightbox` package is done precisely for that:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption, copyrightbox}
\captionsetup{justification = centering}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!h]
  \centering
  \copyrightbox[l]{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{ernst_vierge}}{Museum Ludwig, Köln}
  \caption{La Vierge corrigeant l’enfant Jésus devant trois témoins\,\\\textit{Max Ernst} (1891--1976)}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It does the job but it adds some space between the picture and the `\caption`, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: It is LaTeX  that adds some vertical skip (10pt by default, if I remember well). You can change that easily with the `caption` package:  just write in your preamble `\captionsetup{skip=4pt}`, say, if you want to reduce it to 4pt.

Comment: I already use `skip=2pt`, I wanted to know if I can have all the captions at the same distance from the picture without having to add a `\copyrightbox` everywhere.

Comment: @Arch Stanton: well, yes of course. The `\copyrightbox` is there only  for the ‘copyright’. But maybe you mean all your fidures will have a caption *and* a copyright text?

Comment: No, not all of my figures have a `\copyrightbox` so now those which have one are further away from the figure, unless I reduce the `skip` and put a `\copyrightbox` (empty if not needed) everywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce this. Could you provide a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: See edit in the question.

Answer (score 9):

One way would be to use a `rotatebox` inside a `figure` environment like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \rotatebox{90}{\tiny Hans Hillewaert (WIKIPEDIA)}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{squid.jpg}
    \caption{A Nice Squid}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

this will give something like this :
[image: Squid with side caption]